# Scala dataframe when write to CSV need to remove "" to empty

Tags: dataframe, scala, csv

We have scale code which is reading parquet files loading to Dataframes and then writing to CSV files. We are seeing for some columns when there is no value, CSV is having empty quotes(like this ""), actually when there is no value, we need empty without quotes in CSV, appreciate for any suggestion .

eg:
Present
col1, col2, col3
"abc","sss","","aaa"

Expected
col1, col2, col3,col4
"abc","sss",,"aaa"

Code snippet:

```
tableDF.coalesce(1).write.option("header", includeColumnNames).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(pathToFolderWithCSV)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is fixed, after adding code with emptyValue "" as below.

```
tableDF.coalesce(1).write.option("header", includeColumnNames).option("emptyValue","").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(pathToFolderWithCSV)
```